# addTarget:action:forControlEvents: selector syntax when target is nil?

Tags: swift, uicontrol, responder-chain

I would like a parent `ViewController` to handle Target-Actions generated by one of its child `ViewControllers`.

According to the Apple docs this should be possible by setting `target` to `nil` and following the responder chain.

> If you specify nil for the target object, the control searches the
>   responder chain for an object that defines the specified action
>   method. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol

But how do I write the action method signature when `target` is `nil`?

Typically you enclose the function name in `#selector()` which gives you compile time checks that a method exists with that signature. Like so:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
         self.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchDown)
    }

    func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) { }

}
```

But since `target` is `nil` the compiler complains because it can't find it:

```
// ! Use of unresolved identifier "buttonPressed(sender:)"
button.addTarget(nil, action: #selector(buttonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchDown)
```

I tried initializing a Selector using a String, but the compiler also complains.

```
    // ! String literal is not a valid Objective-C selector
    button.addTarget(nil, action: Selector("buttonPressed(sender:)"), for: .touchDown)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to prefix with the name of the defining class.

```
    button.addTarget(nil, action: #selector(MyViewController.buttonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchDown)
```

FYI I got the answer through [this nice blog post from Jan 2016](http://swiftandpainless.com/utilize-the-responder-chain-for-target-action/), downloading the source files, and having XCode convert it to Swift 3 syntax :-)

Comment: But this surely defeats the point: that a responder can respond to the selector without a responder being explicitly pre-defined..

Comment: How do you mean? Because now the selector must be a method defined in `MyViewController`? I want my child's actions to be handled by its parent, so I want my selector to be defined in the parent.

Comment: The idea of the responder chain mechanism is that a responder is the first in a chain of possible responders without explicitly naming which responder will respond, allowing for loose coupling..

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, note double parentheses to avoid warning:
`NSApp.sendAction(Selector(("enterActivationNumber:")), to: nil, from: sender)`